# Draw a triangle knowing its sides

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's have a triangle with sides AB = 80, BC = 50, CA = 40.
It is necessary to draw a triangle whose sides would be equal to these values.Tried to do it via AddPolygon, but I think it's not quite the right solution

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (index == 1) 
            {
                Point[] myArray =
             {
                 new Point(80, 50),
                 new Point(50, 40),
                 new Point(40, 80),
             };

                GraphicsPath Path = new GraphicsPath();
                Path.AddPolygon(myArray);

                Pen P = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
                e.Graphics.DrawPath(P, Path);
            }
        }
```

Comment: How good is your trigonometry? Draw the triangle out on paper with one vertex at the origin and see if you can figure out what the coordinates of the other two vertices are.

Comment: The side lengths do not convert directly to points. To do it by hand, you'd draw line `40` units long and mark one end as `A` and the other as `C`. Then use a compass to draw a circle `80` units from `A` and another one `50` units from `C`, pick one of the intersecting points and label it `B`, and then you have your 3 points. Something like this: https://www.mathopenref.com/consttrianglesss.html (click "run")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since numbers represent lengths, not coordinates, they cannot be used in the API directly: you need to do some math before you start drawing.

First, let's decide on the location and orientation of our triangle: vertex `A` would be at `(0, 0)`, and side `AB` would lie on the `X` axis, so point `B` would be at `(80, 0)`. Now it's all about figuring out the location of point `C`. You can figure it out by solving two equations together:

(x-80)<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = 40<sup>2</sup>
x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = 50<sup>2</sup>

The math is easy enough for a seventh grader who's good at math, so I wouldn't bore you with the solution. It yields `x=45.62` and `y=20.45`. Plug these numbers into your program to draw your triangle.

Obviously, this draws the triangle in only one, easy-to-do, orientation. To move the triangle, adjust coordinates of its vertices by the same number. Rotating is a lot trickier; you would need to look it up in your favorite book on analytic geometry.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I'll sort it out.